# Change time format in Django Views

Tags: python, django, date, format

`import`datetime

in my **django views**  to save the time in **database**

and

`now = datetime.datetime.now()`

when i am **saving** its value in database it **returns** something like

> 2013-04-28 22:54:30.223113

how can i remove

> 223113  from  2013-04-28 22:54:30.223113

part  please suggest how can i do this ...

Comment: in what kind of field do you save?

Comment: its a text field but due to some reason i cant change this into datetime field

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `microsecond=0`. But I can not find this feature in documentation.'

```
>>> now = datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0)
>>> print now
2013-04-29 12:47:28
```

Answer (score 12):

You should ideally be using datetime field in your database. But if there is a constraint that
you go to store date as a string use this to format it :

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") 
'2013-04-29 12:17:55'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do this way :

```
import datetime
n = datetime.datetime.now() # you'll get the datetime you already have
n.strftime("%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S") 
# Now you have the string of the datatime with the format 
# day/month/year hour:minute:seconde
```

Look at this section section : http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime

Have fun !