# django datefime filed ignore milisecond and extra data

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

By default, Django DateTime filed save and show second and millisecond and extra info in data for example it saves and show date like:

```
2018-07-21 05:27:29.736956+00:00
```

is there any way to or any global function to ignore extra info and get only date and time when trying to retrieve data? like

```
2018-07-21 05:27:29
```

model:

```
class Enrolled(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, to_field='product_id',
                                related_name='enroll')
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

serilizer

```
class EnrolledSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    ptitle = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    instructor = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    instructorid = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    pslug = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_instructor(self, object):
        return object.product.author.username

    def get_instructorid(self, object):
        return object.product.author.id

    def get_ptitle(self, obj):
        return obj.product.title

    def get_pslug(self, obj):
        return obj.product.slug

    class Meta:
        model = Enrolled
        fields = [
            'id',
            'user',
            'product',
            'ptitle',
            'instructorid',
            'pslug',
            'instructor',
            'created_date',
        ]

        read_only_fields = ['product', 'created_date', 'id', 'user', 'instructor', 'instructorid', 'pslug', 'ptitle']
```

//edit :

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': ("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (

        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer',
    )
}

USE_I18N = False

USE_L10N = False

USE_TZ = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can set datetime format for your `created_date`, by settings for all datetime fields:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DATETIME_FORMAT': "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M",
}
```

only for current serializer, and if your other fields it is just reference you can use `source` option, for example:

```
class EnrolledSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    created_date = serializers.DateTimeField(format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    ptitle = serializers.CharField(source='product.author.username')
```

read the docs: [date-and-time-fields](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#date-and-time-fields) and [source](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source).

Comment: i used REST_FRAMEWORK option but it not work for me i post setting in post can you please check why it not working ?

Answer (score 0):

Seems relevant to [Change time format in Django Views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16272564/)

Use

```
microsecond=0
```

Or you can format your datetime in view as you want following that template filter https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-date

```
{{ value|date:"Y-m-d" }} {{ value|time:"H:i:s" }}
```